# Data cleaning using R : use str_remove() function

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a problem in cleaning my data using R. My dataframe looks like this;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMTSq.png)

I need to clean the new_sub_weather$HOURLYPrecip column
1: Change 'T' value to '0.0'
2: Remove data value which has 's' at the back such as '0.02s'

My coding is like this;

```
new_sub_weather['HOURLYPrecip'][new_sub_weather['HOURLYPrecip'] == 'T'] <- '0.0'
str_remove(new_sub_weather$HOURLYPrecip, "s$")
unique(new_sub_weather$HOURLYPrecip)
```

But I didn't manage to remove the character 's'.

Comment: Don't use pictures. Use `dput` to generate a text representation of the data object. Also R is a functional language. Operations on an object often have no lasting effect. You need to assign the results to a new object name and then work on that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `readr::parse_number` which will automatically remove `"s"` from `"0.02s"` and turn the values to numeric.

```
new_sub_weather$HOURLYPrecip[new_sub_weather$HOURLYPrecip == "T"] <- 0
new_sub_weather$HOURLYPrecip <- readr::parse_number(new_sub_weather$HOURLYPrecip)
```

For eg -

```
x <- c(0, 12.1, '1.2s', '0.0', '0.02s')
readr::parse_number(x)
#[1]  0.00 12.10  1.20  0.00  0.02
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace "T" with "0.0" and "s" with "" using `str_replace`:

```
a <- c(0.00, 0.06, "T", "0.02s")

stringr::str_replace(a, c("T","s"), c("0.0",""))
#> [1] "0"    "0.06" "0.0"  "0.02"
```

Answer (score 0):

was stuck with the same problem and after hours of sweet painful study, arrived at this, give it a try and let me know if it helps.

```
    new_sub_weather["HOURLYPrecip"][new_sub_weather["HOURLYPrecip"] == "T"] <- "0.0"

    new_sub_weather$HOURLYPrecip <- str_replace(new_sub_weather$HOURLYPrecip, "s$", "")

    unique(new_sub_weather$HOURLYPrecip)
```